# SlidingExpiration using authentication mode="None"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-identity, owin, session-cookies

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC application session, trying to implement ADFS authentication with OWIN using "`UseCookieAuthentication`" and "`UseWsFederationAuthentication`".

The ADFS authentication only works when I set **authentication mode="None"** in the web.config

The problem is that when I set authentication mode="**None**" and, for example, session timeout = 2 minutes, the session ends at 2 minutes after the login. Sliding expiration is not working and the user gets logged out even while using the site.

When I set authentication mode="**Forms**" the session behavies perfectlly and the user gets logged out only if 2 minutes passed after the last request, but the ADFS authentication stops working.

Does someone knows something about this problem?

The ADFS service is from an external partner, I don't know the configuration.

Here is my code:

```
<sessionState timeout="2" cookieName="MB_SEID"></sessionState>

<authentication mode="None">
<forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" defaultUrl="/" path="/" name="UID" timeout="2" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)sessionTimeout),
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnResponseSignIn = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)sessionTimeout);
                ctx.Options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            }
        }
    });

    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Wtrealm = realm,
        MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
        Wreply = replay,
        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        UseTokenLifetime = false // set to false to manage session with the cookie middleware
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you need to post some of your configuration for this ADFS auth.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My configuration was alright. The problem was an internal session management unknown by me.
Thank you all for your help.